# Horaas Shaa (emergency order) of kollel

Tags: history

I've been told in conversation that kollel, i.e. learning for an extended period of time after marriage, was a horaas Shaa — a temporary emergency order of Rabbinical ruling, made to fight the startling ignorance of Torah knowledge.
What is the history of this ?

(I have a vague memory of seeing something related to this on mi yodea; can't find it now...)

Comment: I believe the beis Yosef brings something similar "es la'asos lashem heferu torasecha" when countering the Rambam's Psak that says one may not rely on tzedaka and sit and learn

Comment: Also see my answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138445/work-and-talmud-torah/138647#138647

Comment: @Loani the first one is similar, though it doesn't really answer my question. Seeing that the question was asked, in a way, seven years ago leads me to believe that it is a widespread idea with no clear basis...